# Why my ElegantNumberButton is not showing +(Plus) sign?

Tags: android, android-layout

my xml code

```
<com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:finalNumber="20"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:textSize="8sp"/>
```

i am using ElegantNumberButton that version:

```
implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
```

is there any version problem with that?

Comment: use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`  instead of a fixed size

Comment: if i use this it working but is there any way to work in ```android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="30dp" ```

Comment: no, because probably the text size is not dynamically calculated based on button dimensions (and this is correct, you can't have touch target too small)

Comment: oh! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it as @Matpag say

```
<com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
      android:id="@+id/number_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
      app:finalNumber="20"
      app:initialNumber="1"
      app:textSize="8sp"/>
```

you can not change `android:layout_width` & `android:layout_height`